# Cannot display map with D3 - Cannot read property

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

The json referenced in the code for world map centered in Europe (https://bl.ocks.org/MariellaCC/0055298b94fcf2c16940) has features property. When I run the code locally I get the error:

> "Cannot read property 'features' of null".

I downloaded the `"ne_50m_admin_0_countries_simplified.json"` file and checked that it wasn't corrupted or missing the property. What am I missing? Thank you.

```
//Width and height
var w = 800;
var h = 600;

//Define map projection


var projection = d3.geo.mercator() //utiliser une projection standard pour aplatir les pôles, voir D3 projection plugin
                       .center([ 13, 52 ]) //comment centrer la carte, longitude, latitude
                       .translate([ w/2, h/2 ]) // centrer l'image obtenue dans le svg
                       .scale([ w/1.5 ]); // zoom, plus la valeur est petit plus le zoom est gros 

//Define path generator
var path = d3.geo.path()
                 .projection(projection);


//Create SVG
var svg = d3.select("#container")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

//Load in GeoJSON data
d3.json("ne_50m_admin_0_countries_simplified.json", function(json) {

    //Bind data and create one path per GeoJSON feature
    svg.selectAll("path")
       .data(json.features)
       .enter()
       .append("path")
       .attr("d", path)
       .attr("stroke", "rgba(8, 81, 156, 0.2)")
       .attr("fill", "rgba(8, 81, 156, 0.6)");

});
```

Comment: 1. Are you using a server? 2. Is the file in the same folder of your HTML file?

Comment: I'm running a local python web server "python -m http.server 8888" and the file is in the same directory as the html file. I can run other d3 charts but not this map.

Comment: What happens when you `console.log(json)`.

Comment: It returns null

Comment: So, that's your problem. If the file is OK (as you said in your question), there is no misspelling in the name and it is in the same folder, it should not return `null`.

Comment: Thanks Gerardo! Something is wrong with the file. I downloaded a new one and it works.